# Identify this caterpillar

Tags: zoology, species-identification

[image: unknown caterpillar]

Could anyone try to help identify this caterpillar, there are loads of them all over my garden and I've got three of them in a makeshift caterpillar house. I've had them for about a week and they've grown to about 3 or 4 centimetres in length and I am yet to see any of them form pupae. I am from London by the way. 
EDIT: they don't seem to be too fussy about what they eat, I have found them on honeysuckle, rose bushes and even some nibbling on the bind weed I've pulled recently.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @rg255 thanks, once I am home I will take some closer pictures, I believe there were a lot on my honeysuckle but I will give a full list later.

Comment: @rg255 I have added new, closer images and a brief description of the plants I've found them on. Two of the ones I have been looking after have seemed to now be staying close to the dirt level I've put in the tank (possibly going to cocoon under ground or in the floor???).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the animal is not a caterpillar but larva.

The species is [Abia lonicerae](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abia_lonicerae) Sawfly, discovered by Linnaeus 1758.

([Another picture](http://mywildlifefriendlygarden.zenfolio.com/p415675779/h6276BECE#h6276bece))

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the sawfly considered a pest? Should I worried about the massive population of them in my garden?

Comment: Thanks for the response, that explains why I couldn't find them anywhere on the Internet by searching for caterpillars!

Comment: Are you sure that it's that particular species (if so, what characters are you using?), or could it be a related species (*Abia sp.*)? +1

Comment: @fileunderwater I am, actually... the images are related to specific species from the answer.

Comment: How do you distinguish it from other species in *Abia*?

Comment: @user16370 With regards to pest status, the larvae will eat the plants in your garden, potentially causing damage.  The adults are relatively harmless.

Comment: Larvae of this species do feed on honeysuckle (Lonicera) foliage